# Using request across 2 different struts-action flows

Tags: java, action, httprequest, struts-action, struts-1

I have a struts action flow(struts-1.x framework), which, when executes, the action class `ActionFlowActionUnit1.java` sets a `String` variable `varName` to `request` using the code

```
request.setAttribute("varNameFromRequest", varName);
```

and the flow finally leads to the loading of a `jsp` `Page1.jsp`.

Now, `Page1.jsp` contains a button, which, when clicked, initiates a new struts action flow, which has the action class `ActionFlowActionUnit2.java`. In this class, I want to use the `varName` which I had set in request using `request.getAttribute()`.

How can I do it **WITHOUT USING SESSION**?

Technically, I'm not sure if achieving this using `request`is possible, because, triggering a new struts-action will lose all other information in the `request` that was previously set (if I'm correct).

I couldn't get anything from Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, it is not feasible technically as you want it (every http request from the browser creates a new `HttpServletRequest` object)

You have 2 options:

- Using the `Session`, which you want to avoid as far as I understand
- Bring back and forth some parameter into every successive request with the value you would like to keep.

The second option would mean to store some parameter inside your Page1.jsp `<form>` with the variable you need your second action to receive, and then rinse and repeat.  This is a pure html form solution.

If you are implementing a complex flow, this looks a fair case to have a look at Spring Webflow.  There you can manage flow-level variables, which are stored at a "different" scope than request or session, and looks exactly what you want.

http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/